# https://graph-video.facebook.com/ Redirect After Uploading

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I am using the following code it successfully upload video but after uploading it show some ID page. Can any one help how to redirect page to my desired location after uploading video successfully.

Thanks in advance.

```
$app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
$app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
$my_url = "YOUR_POST_LOGIN_URL";
$video_title = "TITLE FOR THE VIDEO";
$video_desc = "DESCRIPTION FOR THE VIDEO";
$page_id = "YOUR_PAGE_ID";

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

echo '<html><body>';

if(empty($code)) {
    // Get permission from the user to publish to their page.
    $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
        . "&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages";
    echo('<script>top.location.href="' . $dialog_url . '";</script>');
} else {

    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
        . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
        . "&code=" . $code;
    $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

    $accounts_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?" . $access_token;
    $response = file_get_contents($accounts_url);

    $resp_obj = json_decode($response,true);
    $accounts = $resp_obj['data'];

    foreach($accounts as $account) {
        if($account['id'] == $page_id) {
            $access_token = $account['access_token'];
            break;
        }
    }

    $post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/" . $page_id . "/videos?"
        . "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc
        . "&access_token=". $access_token;

    echo "<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" '.$post_url.' "
        method="POST">";
    echo "Please choose a file:";
    echo "<input name="file" type="file">";
    echo "<input type="submit" value="Upload" />";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make the video upload to facebook happen on your server side, instead of your visitors browser, so you can catch the output and send the visitors browser to the right place.

Your users will upload their files on your server first, then you can use curl to send the video to facebook, and after its finished you can redirect the user.

*Examples*:

1. Facebook Graph api video object: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/
2. Command line Curl examples: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5227607/posting-an-embedded-video-link-using-the-facebook-graph-api
3. Example with Facebook PHP api: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9018213/video-post-on-timeline-not-playing-inline

Comment: can u share some coding links from where i can get help

Comment: Added some links, i hope those help.